# problems with handling unicode characters in python

Tags: python, unicode

I wrote the below code for writing the contents to the file,

```
   with codecs.open(name,"a","utf8") as myfile:
         myfile.write(str(eachrecord[1]).encode('utf8'))
         myfile.write(" ")
         myfile.write(str(eachrecord[0]).encode('utf8'))
         myfile.write("\n")`
```

The above code does not work properly when writing uni-code characters....Even though i am using codecs and doing the encoding. I keep getting the error

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)

Can anyone see where i am doing it wrong ?

**Edit:**

```
with codecs.open(name,"a","utf8") as myfile:
                    myfile.write(unicode(eachrecord[1]))
                    myfile.write(" ")
                    myfile.write(unicode(eachrecord[0]))
                    myfile.write("\n")
```

This worked..Thanks for all the quick comments and answers..that really helps ..I did not realize that python has 'unicode' option until you guys told me

Comment: What type is `eachrecord[1]`? `str` is making the mess I guess, use `unicode` instead.

Comment: And I think you do not even have to encode the unicode string, as the file opened using codecs should handle it.

Comment: eachrecord[1] can be string or a number

Comment: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found..any suggestions on how to resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `str()` calls. They are doing an implicit encoding with the default encoding (`ascii` in this case).

Comment: Thank you, i keep getting this error "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'" when i remove the str() calls